# Cannot connect GitLab to GKE Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, continuous-integration

I am trying to create a CI Pipeline for my GitLab project to deploy my microservices automatically on a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster.

Sadly I am unable to use the build-In native Google Cloud Integration from GitLab as it isn't properly configured, so I have to do it the manual way. I am following [this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/#adding-an-existing-kubernetes-cluster) to link my cluster to gitlab, but after setting everything up, installing Helm Tiller fails with a Kubernetes 401 error.

I suspect, that it fails because I didn't give the `container.clusterRoleBindings.create` role to my service account, however I created it using the commands given in the guide and as I can't see this account in the Google IAM service accounts list, I have no Idea how to give it to my Kubernetes service account.

Does anyone have an idea how I can give my service account that permission or what I have to do different in order to get the gitlab gke integration up and running?

Comment: Can you list all service accounts `kubectl get sa --all-namespaces` ?

Comment: There was a similar case on Stackoverflow and eventually cluster re-creation solved the problem. Can you try it out?


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732383/there-was-a-problem-authenticationg-with-your-cluster-when-i-making-gitlab-and?noredirect=1#comment100049616_56732383

Answer (score 0):

Please check similar cases on the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732383/there-was-a-problem-authenticationg-with-your-cluster-when-i-making-gitlab-and/56749988#56749988) and on the [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/8897)

You can not use same Kubernetes cluster integration configuration in multiple projects, otherwise it will fail to authenticate

Workaround for this is to

1. re-create a cluster
2. use [CI Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) (`KUBE_NAMESPACE` and `KUBECONFIG`) instead of using Kubernetes integration config.